# How do I use fgets along with malloc to create an array of strings?

Tags: c

I am taking in a variable amount of lines of string using fgets. The end of each line is marked by a new line. I am trying to allocate an array of strings (using malloc). Each index of the array will point to each line of the text that is entered from the user. This was really tough to explain so here is an example:

Using fgets and malloc, allow the user to enter multiple lines of strings. The user will signal the end of the strings with a '.' on a newline. Each line of the multiple strings will be stored as a string in a dynamically allocated array. The output of the program must print each line in reverse order.

Ex:
Enter string:
(this is sample input)

```
The sky is blue
The grass is green
I love life
.
```

(this should be the output)

```
I love life
The grass is green
The sky is blue
```

I have this so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char charsOnLine[1000];
    char **poem;
    int i;
    int j;


    fgets(charsOnLine, 1000, stdin); //runs only once

    while (charsOnLine[0] != '.')
    {

        poem = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 3);
        for(j = 0; j < strlen(charsOnLine); j++)
        {
            poem[j] = malloc(sizeof(strlen(charsOnLine)));
            strcpy(poem[j], charsOnLine);
        }

        fgets(charsOnLine, 1000, stdin);
    }

    for (j = 0; j < strlen(*poem); j++) //test to print each line of the poem (not in reverse)
    {
        printf("%s\n",poem[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am have just started with double pointers, pointers, dynamically allocating memory, fgets() and putting them all together is giving me some trouble.

In my code, I'm testing to see if it'll print each line I enter the same way I entered it, but it is printing the last entered string 4 times instead of each different line.

Once I figure out how to print each entered line, I will figure out how to print them backwards.

Comment: You keep reallocating `poem`. Take that line out of the loop so it only runs once.

Comment: `poem = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 3);
        for(j = 0; j < strlen(charsOnLine); j++)
        {
            poem[j] = ...` is strange.  Why allocate room for 3 pointers and then iterate possible way more than 3 times?

Comment: @chux Like i said above I'm still learning. Visualizing what is going on is tough for me lol. I just need more practice

Answer (score 1):

There's a rather simple solution to your "in reverse order" problem, which does not even require dynamic memory allocation but just recursion:

```
void readRecursive() {
     char charsOnLine[1000];
     if (fgets(charsOnLine, 1000, stdin) && charsOnLine[0] != '.') {
        readRecursive();
     }
     fputs(charsOnLine, stdout);
}
```

Comment: I would love to use this method, but I am required to use dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char charsOnLine[1000];
    char **poem = NULL;
    size_t size = 0, current;


    while (fgets(charsOnLine, 1000, stdin) != NULL && charsOnLine[0] != '.')
    {
        char **tmp;
        tmp = realloc(poem, (size + 1) * sizeof(*poem));
        if(tmp)
        {
            poem = tmp;
            poem[size] = malloc(strlen(charsOnLine) + 1);
            if(poem[size])
            {
                strcpy(poem[size++], charsOnLine);
            }
        }
    }

    current = size;
    while(current--)
    {
        fputs(poem[current], stdout);
    }

    /* do something more with your read poem */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see you put the fgets function into the while loop arguments. I was not aware that you could do that. What does fputs do?

Comment: how would i free all the memory allocated?